# Clickable Hyperlink in GoogleScript HTML Service is not opening

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm currently working on a small code to show via HTML Service a "Pop-Up" Window to the user. In this Window (showMOdalDialog) there is a href with a hyperlink. The Window is opening, the hyperlink is clickable but nothing happens.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you!

I already tried DocUI / HTML Service

CODE:

```
var url; // it is populated by a different function
```

**Code.gs:**

```
function openHyperlink_new() {

var ui  = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Hyperlink');
ui.link = url;

  DocumentApp.getUi()
  .showModalDialog(ui.evaluate(),'Test');

}
```

**Hyperlink.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href=<?=link?>>Visit our HTML tutorial</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the target to "_blank" to open the link in a new window and the modal window.

```
<a target="_blank" href=<?=link?>>Visit our HTML tutorial</a>
```

Comment: So easy! :) Thank you very much Works without a problem now :)

Comment: Maybe you can help me again: The Link is working now and the hyperlink is clickable. Do you think it will be able to do the following:

When I click on the link the Spreadsheet app (which is open in Tab1) is closed and then hyperlink opens in tab2? (The other way round is also fine)

Comment: No, the IFRAME cannot close the parent window. If the answer resolves your issue, consider accepting it as the answer.